# I bought a eBook yesterday on Google Play, but can't export it as .epub neither .pdf

Tags: google-play-books, download

It's the first time this happens. Usually I can download all books bought on Google Play in .pdf format at least.

[image]

This time I can't even see the option to download as usual:

[image]

Comment: Does the problem still persists?

Comment: Yes the problem is still the same unfortunately.

Comment: I see that the book 'Design Patterns' is not showing the download option while the other book 'Architecting Angular...' is. IMO, the issue might be with the book. I think you should contact the [Google Play Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/gethelp), they may help you in a better way.

Comment: There is also a same [question](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/25601982/cannnot-download-books-from-play-books?hl=en&msgid=25601982) posted on the Google Play Community which is still unanswered :(